# Forward Slash within a reverse proxy for Wordpress

Tags: iis, redirect, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website within a reverse proxy that generally works fine.

I have noticed a issue today where I delete the trailing forward slash it redirects me to the target (non reverse-proxy) version of the page.

Removing the last forward slash from `www.reverseproxydomain/rpfolder/postname/` directs me to `www.targetdomain/postname/`.

Can anyone advise me on how I can just get it to add the forward slash back on rather than redirecting me to the target domain.

`.htaccess` contents

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What reverse-proxy?

Comment: The reverse proxy I am using for my development site is IIS.  The reverse proxy on the live server is done on our clients load balancer and they pass through all traffic to our server. the .htaccess looks something like this RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Do you want a solution to apply to the reverse-proxies or to Apache?

Comment: Hello there, I have managed to figure this out, I managed to create a 301 redirect to force the trailing forwardslash, i had to put the rule above the permalink generated code to get it to work.  here is my htaccess file now

Answer (score 0):

the htaccess fix is the following

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/car-magazine/$1/ [L,R=301]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```